# Google Dataflow Autoscaling to 0

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using a Google Dataflow streaming pipeline with the default settings.

Thing is, it looks like the pipeline will start off at 1 worker, then scale down to 0 for 10-20 minutes, then up to 1 for 10-40 minutes, then back down.

This causes backups and surges in my PubSub topics, and sets off alerts based on unacknowledged messages. I've adjusted the alerting to accomodate these surges, but it's still odd behavior.

If the traffic through Dataflow is sufficiently low, but not zero, is it expected that the workers will scale to 0 until there is a backlog of work to do?

Comment: I'm pinging a dataflow autoscaling team member to take a look at this and offer an answer.

Comment: @Pablo thanks. We've redeployed the pipeline a few times over the last few weeks and it still happens.

Comment: seems like this is not expected behavior. Do you have a job id?

Comment: @Pablo yup, its: 2017-06-20_10_17_52-11948675662393955767

Comment: We looked at it. Your job does not have autoscaling enabled. The autoscaling UI has a bug in reporting # of workers, but your job is always functioning with one worker. Your job seems to be, at times, spiking in CPU usage and decreasing in throughput. Are there some elements that may require extra processing to cause the backlog? If you want, you can post a question with details about your workload and we can try to figure that out. Perhaps we should close this question. What do you think?

Comment: @Pablo ah ok, thanks. Yeah that makes sense, I was looking into it further today and you're right about auto-scaling not being on. The issue with the job is known, and can't be too easily avoided because of the nature of the data. But now that I know where to look, I can focus on that area. Thanks, and yes this can be closed.